# Why isn't my css affecting my div?

Tags: html, css

My css has been working fine on the past 2 pages of a site I am working on, but all of the sudden, I have a div that I am trying to style, but nothing I put into css takes effect on the div. Maybe I'm missing something simple or have something named wrong, but I *cannot* figure out what is wrong here. Below, I am trying to edit the div "3left", it has an image up top, and a paragraph of text below the image, but I am unable to change the background color, or position the div where I want to within the div "page3". Thanks in advance.

heres the bit of html I am working with:

```
<div id="page3">
            <div id="3left">
              <image src="images/entertop_03.png"></image>
                <h4>text<br>

text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text <a href="#" class="class1">text</a><br>
text</h4>
            </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#page3 {
       background-image: url("../images/page3back_01.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    min-height: 730px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 2em;


}

#3left {
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 440px;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #221f1f;



}
```

Comment: `<image>` doesn't need closing tag.

Comment: @Evgeny Not only does `<image>` not need a closing tag; it's not a tag. It should be `<img .... />`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the ID starts with a number.

The [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) has details on what is allowed.

> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e.,
>   [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under
>   the control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of the
>   HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies
>   outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that
>   element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in XML.
>
> In CSS, identifiers (**including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors**) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: I just noticed that. To clarify, the ID attribute needs to start with an uppercase or lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks @andi. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You have used `<image>` instead of `<img>` and you have used an id starting with a number, Following will work fine.

```css
#page3 {
       background-image: url("../images/page3back_01.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    min-height: 730px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 2em;


}

#left3 {
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 440px;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #221f1f;



}
```

```html
<div id="page3">
            <div id="left3">
              <img src=""></img>
                <h4>text<br>

text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text <a href="#" class="class1">text</a><br>
text</h4>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class identifiers are allowed to start with a number, but ID identifiers are not.

```
[id='1800number_box'] {
 /* does work */
}

#1800number_box {
  /* doesn't work */
}

/* Or, you can "escape" the number, which looks funky but works: */
#\31 800number_box {
  /* does work */
}
/* See: http://mothereff.in/css-escapes */`
```